# Is Grid.MVC compatible with ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, grid.mvc

Before I start messing around with something that doesn't work:

Does Grid.MVC work with ASP.NET MVC 5?

On gridmvc.codeplex.com they just write MVC3/4, but I wonder if anybody tried it with MVC5? You tried it, but it didn't work?

Comment: There are almost no breaking changes from MVC 4 to MVC 5, so I would suspect something that worked for MVC 4 to almost certainly work for MVC 5.

Comment: You should ask this on their codeplex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one: http://mvc-grid.azurewebsites.net
it is more up-to-date.

MVC 5:

```
Install-Package NonFactors.Grid.Mvc5
```

MVC 6:

```
Install-Package NonFactors.Grid.Mvc6
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it works in MVC5.  The website does not indicate 3+ but that's what it is.

I have implimented Grid.Mvc in multiple MVC5 projects using EF6.

I love it, it's really easy to stand up and allow my users to query the data tables.  I would suggest trying it out, but the documentation isn't great. Luckily the documentation they do have is enough to get started.

https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/documentation