# How to export filtered records to excel from Grid.MVC grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, export-to-excel, grid.mvc

We have implemented a grid in our MVC 4 application and used Grid.MVC package for this. It has sorting and filtering enabled.

Our requirement is to export filtered data from this grid.

Can you please provide any reference or hint for this?
Thank You!

Comment: If you have got a solution to this please share it with other users.

Comment: sure, I'll. still looking into it. Simultaneously started implementing custom export logic.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40908261/187650 this grid can export to excel!